# How can we merge two batch files using the Apache Camel Timeout Aggregation Strategy

Tags: apache-camel

I have a requirement to merge two batch files generated through Spring batch. I need to take these files which are output to a particular output directory. I need to use these files to merge the data in both. The header and trailers are same for both the files. Only thing to take care is that the trailer record should have total count of the number of records on the merged file. The files are available with a time lag hence the solution should wait for both files to be available to complete the merge.

Comment: Do you know the order in which these files will be generated? Will that order be maintained every time?

Comment: Yes, There are two files generated one for GB (Great Britain) and another for NI (Northern Ireland). The NI file is always generated first as it has a smaller dataset. The GB file is generated a few hours later. My approach so far is to first access the NI file and remove the trailer and then aggregate the dataset from GB file and then write a trailer record with the total record counts.

Comment: Yes, the order will be maintained every time.